# Is there a way to stealth a taunted minion?

Tags: hearthstone

Whenever I try stealthing a taunt minion the taunt goes away.Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: So question is essentially, can I break the game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there is no way to do so. this is because stealth stops the minion from being attacked or being seen. Another mechanic like this is where immunity makes a minion loose taunt. you can do this by bestial wreathing a beat with taunt and playing a minion with charge and you can still hit face. check this out http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Immune and this http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Stealth

Answer (score 14):

**No.**

This is by design.
For the minion to both prevent attacks to other non-taunt targets **and** to be unable to be targeted would be *way* too powerful. As such, taunt minions loose their taunt ability while they are at stealth.

In most cases, making taunt minions stealthed defeats their point and should be avoided, unless you have some other reason to keep them alive.