# Does Mal'Ganis' status effect apply in the 'Lead from the front' brawl?

Tags: hearthstone

This weeks tavern brawl provides each hero with taunt; this means that minions are safe from attack.

During play I placed down Mal'Ganis, which would make the hero invulnerable (in this game mode would be well OP). I thought the game was in the bag, until my opponent hit it with a 1 power minion and execute.

Do such invulnerable status' apply in this game mode, or have they been disabled?

Comment: I'm fairly sure (but can't source it right now) that if you're invulnerable then taunt doesn't have any effect. So while your hero is invulnerable your minions can be attacked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Immunity doesn't interact with taunt in the way you think it does. [According to the hearthstone wiki](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Immune) a unit (or hero) with taunt and immune would effectively only have the immune, i.e. taunt stops working while the immunity is in effect.

This makes sense for the reasons you've mentioned, make a taunt unit immune, call it a day. So combined with your experience, yes Mal'Ganis does make the hero immune, and then everything can attack your minions.

Comment: Well you learn something new every day! I have only ever used 2 immunity cards and both affect the hero rather than units, so I would have never known that!

Comment: @nickson104 That's because there are only 2 cards in the game that can give a minion immunity. They're both Hunter cards, and they're both only applicable to Beasts, which means you either need one of 4 beast taunt cards (Misha, King of Beasts, Ironfur Grizzly, Silverback patriarch) or a way to give a Beast taunt, which means Hound master, Rusty Horn, Defender of Argus, Sunfury Protector or Enhance-o Mechano. There are other ways, like, Mark of the Wild, Mark of Nature, Coghammer, Ancestral Healing, Hex and Sparring Partner, but those are class cards and thus less likely for a hunter.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs A very thorough explanation of how to be put in such a circumstance! Good to know

Comment: The same thing happens if you stealth a target that has taunt. That minion can be ignored and the other minions can be attacked.

Comment: @Sorean Aha! That's how I knew this, from this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241577/is-there-a-way-to-stealth-a-taunted-minion/241583#241583 - I didn't remember where I knew it from.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Those cards also only give immune for the current turn, so it's worn off by the time the taunt matters.

Comment: There is no way currently to make a minion immune during the turn of it's controller's opponent.

Comment: @ralzarek yes there is, you just have not tried hard enough yet. Hysteria has a Hearthstone Mythbusters episode where they do it. They give the KoB off the opponent Immune and then King Krush the opponent.

Comment: @Sorean Yes I had observed that, I suppose I just never figured the effects were so similar